# Express + Passport different multiple 'local' login at the same time

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I would like to apologize in advance.
I'm not good at English. Also I'm not good at Node. Some "words" may be unsuited or wrong. I can not find any solutions in my language sphere. I'm writing this questions with GoogleTranslation's help.

## MY EQUIPMENT

- Ubuntu 16.04 local and virtualized on OSX
- Node.js 8.11.4
- Express 4.16.0
- Passport 0.4.0

If you need more informations, I will answer.

## MAIN QUESTION

I'm coding web application with two auth system. I want to auth these two auth work together at the same time.
My image is below.

> Admin auth browser once. Then different users log-in and log-out. Without Admin, users can access limited page.

My code withdrown below.

```js
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

var fs = require("fs");
var https = require("https");
var body_parser = require("body-parser");
var crypto = require("crypto");

app.use(body_parser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

var admin_passport = require("passport");
var admin_passport_local = require("passport-local");
var admin_express_session = require("express-session");

app.use(admin_express_session({secret: 'admin_secret',resave: false,saveUninitialized: true, cookie: { secure: true }}));
app.use(admin_passport.initialize());
app.use(admin_passport.session());

var admin_LocalStrategy = admin_passport_local.Strategy;

admin_passport.use(new LocalStrategy({passReqToCallback: true,},
    (req, username, password, done) => {
//not coding yes but not probrem
        if(false){
                return done("ERROR");
        }else if(false){
                return done(null, false);
        }else if(true){
                return done(null, username);
        }
    }
));

admin_passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

admin_passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

function admin_isAuthenticated(req, res, next){
//here is probrem
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) { 
        return next();
    }
    else { 
        res.redirect('/admin_login'); 
    }
}
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
//here is probrem
        app.locals.isAuthenticated = req.isAuthenticated();
        next();
});

var user_passport = require("passport");
var user_passport_local = require("passport-local");
var user_express_session = require("express-session");
app.use(user_express_session({secret: 'user_ecret', resave: false,saveUninitialized: true, cokkie:{secure: true}}));
app.use(user_passport.initialize());
app.use(user_passport.session());
var user_LocalStrategy = user_passport_local.Strategy;

user_passport.use(new user_LocalStrategy({passReqToCallback: true,},
    (req, username, password, done) => {
        if(false){
                return done("ERROR");
        }else if(false){
                return done(null, false);
        }else if(true){
                return done(null, username);
        }
    }
));
user_passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

user_passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

function user_isAuthenticated(req, res, next){
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) { 
        return next();
    }
    else {
        res.redirect('/user_login');
    }
}
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
        app.locals.isAuthenticated = req.isAuthenticated();
        next();
});




var ssl_options = {
        key:    fs.readFileSync('./cert/key.pem'),
        cert:   fs.readFileSync('./cert/cert.pem'),
};

var server = https.createServer(ssl_options, app);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {res.render('index', {});});
app.use('/admin_login', require('./admin_login'));
app.use('/admin_logout',  (req, res) => {req.logout();res.redirect('./');})
app.use('/user_top', admin_isAuthenticated, require('./user_top'));
app.use('/user_login', admin_isAuthenticated,require('./user_login'));
app.use('/user_logout', (req, res) => {req.logout();res.redirect('./');})

server.listen(443);
```

and

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');

router.use((req, res, next) => {
        next();
});

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.render('login',{});
});
router.post('/', passport.authenticate('local',{successRedirect: '/',failureRedirect: '/login',failureFlash: true,}),(req, res) =>{
});

module.exports = router;
```

I want to know how fix or change. If there are other way to solve this problem, welcome.

I would like to ask for cooperation.

Comment: But ... what is your question? what doesnt work?

Answer (score 0):

Passport works only one login system?

req.login(), req.logout() req.Authenticated(), Passport-session ....

Many functions don't identify difference between two login system.